# Discrete Math: Implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If $\neg(P) \to \neg(Q) = Q \to P$ works as a Rule, then why doesn't $\neg(P) \to \neg(Q) = P \to Q$ work as a rule.

Comment: Have you learnt when $X$ implies $Y$ (ie, $X \rightarrow Y$) is true? Ie, for which assignments of true/false to $X$ and $Y$ is $X \rightarrow Y$ true?

Answer (score 1):

You should understand this

Implication is equal to Contra positive

Implication is not equal to converse and inverse.

You can prove this with truth table.

Logical  proving,
 $$\begin{align}
& P \;\to\; Q
\\[1ex] 
  = \quad& \neg P \vee Q & \text{Implication Equivalence}
\\[1ex]
  = \quad& \neg \neg Q \vee \neg P & \text{Commutivity and Double Negation}
\\[1ex]
  = \quad& \neg  Q \;\to\; \neg P & \text{Implication Equivalence}
\end{align}$$

Which proves that  $P\to Q \;=\; \neg Q \to \neg P$

Answer (score 0):

This is best understood in terms of the truth tables for each of these statements.  Let's try the statement $(\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow (P \Rightarrow Q)$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P & Q & \neg P & \neg Q & \neg P\Rightarrow \neg Q & P \Rightarrow Q & \Leftrightarrow \\ \hline
T & T & F & F & T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F & T & T & F & F \\ \hline
F & T & T & F & F & T & F \\ \hline
F & F & T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
\end{array}

You can see that these statement are not logically equivalent.  Can you prove that $(\neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow (Q \Rightarrow P)$?